# Not connecting user using MQTTjs on cloudmqtt

Tags: mqtt, iot

I am having this code in my file (belong to react)

```
const client = mqtt.connect({
  host: 'mqtt://m16.cloudmqtt.com',
  port: 1883,
  username: 'b*******k',
  password: 'gU******S',
});
client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('hello');
  client.subscribe('v');
  client.publish('v', 'chal pa');
});
client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
  if (topic === 'v') {
    console.log('here my topic is v');
    // var connected = (message.toString() === 'true');
  }
  console.log('recived message from mqtt');
  console.log(message);
});
client.on('error', er => {
  console.log(er);
});
```

I am expecting to connect to mqtt broker and receive some message. 

But nothing happened. When i check log file in cloudmqtt.com
[image]

I am stuck here can anybody help. Link to any blog/video that will help will be highly appreciated.

I am using mqttjs

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of errors, they are impossible to search and very hard to actually read. Also asking for links to tutorials is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What type of react app is this? Is it running in a browser?

Comment: @hardillb yes it is running in browser and i know browser is blocking tcp but I am trying and using mqtt or websockets protocols

Answer (score 1):

You have explicitly told the MQTTjs library to use native MQTT rather than MQTT over Websockets by using `mqtt://` on the start of the URI.

If you want to use MQTT over websockets the URI should start with `ws://`

Secondly you are using port 1883, this is normally used for native MQTT not MQTT over websockets. The cloudmqtt [docs](https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-websocket.html) suggest you should be using a port number that starts with a `3` to access the websockets listener.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and time you have given. But I have created 2 sub one is react and one in terminal. The react is showing error in connection and terminal is receiving message. I tried tcp,ws,mqtt but non is able to connect through browser( react ). Is their any magic that will solve this problem ?

Comment: Look  at the second part of my answer.... (also if you have a new problem, which this is, ask a new question and include ALL the relevant details, e.g. the error messages)